# How to import CSV rows to SQL database columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

My source is a CSV file which has column names and its related data in rows. How to do manual mapping rows to columns in SQL. Below is the file structure.

CSV file

| EmpNo | ColumnNames | ColumnValues |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EmpName | 'John' |
| 1 | EmpDOB | '08/30/1985' |
| 1 | EmpDesignation | 'DBA' |

Table : EmployeeDetails

| EmpNo | EmpName | EmpDOB | EmpDesignation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 08/30/1985 | DBA |

Comment: Use a `PIVOT` or conditional aggregation. Personally, I'd suggest the latter. If you don't know what the names of the columns will be, you'll need to use dynamic pivoting.

Comment: You've readded the tag [[tag:ssms-2014]] here; what does SSMS 2014, the IDE-like application for SQL Server 2008-2014, have to do with the problem?

Comment: You import them, in that format, in to a staging table, *then* transform the results, before inserting them in to the destination table. For a variety of reasons, you should always stage and validate your data *before* inserting it in to a live table. (For example, validating the  date values, or that the given designation actually exists.)

Comment: Just to add to MatBailie's comment.   Staging & validating the data in this case is particularly important.  Importing an EAV structure, you run the risk of new elements at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use openrowset to get data from csv file. Here an example that could help you.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (EmpNo, EmpName, EmpDesignation)
SELECT EmpNo, ColumnValues, ColumnNames
FROM OPENROWSET('BULK', 'C:\path\to\myFile.csv',
FORMATFILE = 'C:\path\to\myFormatFile.fmt') AS rows;
```

you have to improve columns declared in insert into table and select to matching csv columns with table columns.